# NetBeans replace character with regular expression for end of line

Tags: php, netbeans

I am using netbeans 8.1 , i have legacy php code 5.2 and i have to migrate to 5.6. The major problem is the

I do not know how to search

So:

```
<?
echo "hello world";
```

Should be:

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for `<?` and then any number of spaces until the end of the line

```
<\?\s*$
```

Or, if you know that those characters are always at the only characters on the line

```
^\s*<\?\s*$
```

**Replacing**

Final regex that will keep whitespace in front of the tag (you'll want that in case there are blank lines before the php tag)

Find:

```
^(\s*)<\?\s*$
```

Replace:

```
\1<?php
```

`^` anchors to the start of a line

`()` anything inside is part of a capturing group that can be referenced by using `\1`

`\s` finds (almost) any whitespace (including tabs, newlines, and spacea)

`*` is a modifier that means "match the previous character 0 or more times" (so `\s*` would match any sequential whitespace characters. Including several blank lines in a row)

`<` is not special, means a literal `<`

`\?` means a literal `?` have to escape it cause it means "match previous character 0 or 1 times" (similar to the `*`)

`$` anchors to the end of the line

Make sure you enable regular expressions when searching.

Comment: That works for me =) thank you. Furthermore i had a problem with the encoding, my project was in utf-8 but most of the files were encoding in ANSI. The solution was use the regular expression with project encoding UTF-8 and for the files that were in ANSI use windows-1252 that is the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for `new-line` chatacter then enable regex search and search exactly for `[\r\n]` (*with the square braces*).